# Prove $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-ax^{2}-\frac{b}{x^{2}}) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\mathrm{e}^{-2\sqrt{ab}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is Example 8.4.1 from Chapter 8 (The Normal Integral) of *[Irresistible Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521796369)* by Boros and Moll. The authors outlined a solution method, which I will provide in full here. My question: is there another way to obtain this result?

Here is the solution of Boros and Moll with their notation.

Let
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}(a,b) := \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-ax^{2}-\frac{b}{x^{2}}) \mathrm{d} x
\label{eq:iic8-1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Making the substitution $t=x\sqrt{a}$ yields
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-ax^{2}-\frac{b}{x^{2}}) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} 
\mathrm{exp}(-t^{2}-\frac{ab}{t^{2}}) \mathrm{d} t
\label{eq:iic8-2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Letting $ab=c$ we call the integral in equation \eqref{eq:iic8-2} $f(c)$,
\begin{equation}
f(c) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-t^{2}-\frac{c}{t^{2}}) \mathrm{d} t
\label{eq:iic8-3}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
so that 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L}(a,b) = \frac{f(ab)}{\sqrt{a}}
\label{eq:iic8-4}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
In equation \eqref{eq:iic8-3} we let $y=\sqrt{c}/t$
\begin{equation}
f(c) = \sqrt{c} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-y^{2}-\frac{c}{y^{2}}) y^{-2} \mathrm{d} y
\label{eq:iic8-5}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

Combining equations \eqref{eq:iic8-3} and \eqref{eq:iic8-5}, we have
\begin{equation}
f(c) = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-t^{2}-\frac{c}{t^{2}}) \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{t^{2}} \right) \mathrm{d} t
\label{eq:iic8-6}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
Now we let $s = t - \sqrt{c}/t$
\begin{equation}
f(c) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{- 2\sqrt{c}}}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-s^{2}) \mathrm{d} s = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{e}^{- 2\sqrt{c}} \lim_{z \to \infty} \mathrm{erf}(z) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{e}^{- 2\sqrt{c}}
\label{eq:iic8-7}
\tag{7}
\end{equation}
Combining equations \eqref{eq:iic8-1}, \eqref{eq:iic8-4}, and \eqref{eq:iic8-7} yields our result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-ax^{2} - {b \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\root{ab}\bracks{\root{a \over b}x^{2} + \root{b \over a}{1 \over x^{2}}}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

With $\ds{\pars{a \over b}^{1/4}\,\,x = \expo{\theta}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-ax^{2} - {b \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}\cosh\pars{2\theta}}
\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[4mm] = &\
\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}\cosh\pars{2\theta}}
\bracks{\cosh\pars{\theta} + \sinh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}
\cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ \equiv\ \sinh\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,\,&\
2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-4\root{ab}t^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}}
\bracks{{1 \over \root{4\root{ab}}}\,{\root{\pi} \over 2}} =
\color{#f00}{{\root{\pi} \over 2}\,{\expo{-2\root{ab}} \over \root{a}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution.  I pursued differently and obtained an extra factor of $\frac12$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm reading carefully your answer to see the 'difference'.

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo.  I've edited.  Oh, and +1 for this nice solution.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV You're welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin, this was the type of solution I was seeking.

Comment: @poweierstrass Glad it was useful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

A slick way is to exploit [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html). For any $c>0$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} e^{2\sqrt{c}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-x^2-\frac{c}{x^2}\right)\,dx&=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{c}}{x}\right)^2\right]\,dx\\&=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}. \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Cool tool, but I didn't understand the last identity: you called $\left(x - \frac{\sqrt{c}}{x}\right) = x$?

Comment: @FourierTransform: please have a look at Glasser's master theorem linked here and you will understand the magic beyond that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, good solution and thanks for the introduction to Glasser's master theorem. I will have to add it to my list of integration tricks.

Comment: The theorem is fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the steps in @FelixMarin's answer were not obvious. Here I expand upon his answer so that it will be easier to follow.

1. $\mathrm{e}^{z} = \cosh(z) + \sinh(z)$
2. $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cosh(z) + \sinh(z) \mathrm{d} z = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} \cosh(z) + \sinh(z) \mathrm{d} z 
   + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \cosh(z) + \sinh(z) \mathrm{d} z$$
   In the first integral, let $z=-y$,
   $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} \cosh(z) + \sinh(z) \mathrm{d} z = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \cosh(y) - \sinh(y) \mathrm{d} y$$
   Addition yields,
   $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cosh(z) + \sinh(z) \mathrm{d} z = 2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \cosh(z) \mathrm{d} z$$