# Laplace Transform of $ \frac {e^\frac{-a^2}{4t}}{\sqrt {\pi t}} $

Tags: laplace-transform

Can you please show me the solution for the Laplace transform of

$ \frac {e^\frac{-a^2}{4t}}{\sqrt {\pi t}} $

using the definition of Laplace.

The answer must be:

$ \frac {e^\frac {a}{\sqrt s}}{\sqrt s} $

And also what properties of Laplace must be used in solving this type of problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your attempts and have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909074/prove-int-limits-0-infty-mathrmexp-ax2-fracbx2-mathrmd/1909081#1909081

Comment: the result must be $\frac{\mathrm e^{-a\sqrt s}}{\sqrt {s}}$ (see n. 10  [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/laplace3.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-st}\frac {\mathrm e^\frac{-a^2}{4t}}{\sqrt {\pi t}}\,\mathrm d t$$

Set $u^2=st$, and then $\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\mathrm du=\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\mathrm dt$, so the integral becomes 
$$
F(s)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-u^2}\frac {\mathrm e^\frac{-a^2s }{4u^2}}{\sqrt {\pi s}}\,2\,\mathrm d u=\frac{2}{\sqrt {\pi s}}\times\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-u^2-\frac{\beta }{u^2}}\,\mathrm d u=\frac{2}{\sqrt {\pi s}}\times \frac12\sqrt\pi\mathrm e^{-2\sqrt\beta}
$$
where $\frac{a^2s}{4}=\beta$. So We find

> $$
> F(s)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-a\sqrt s}}{\sqrt {s}}
> $$